# Docx4J Table font type ignored

Tags: java, docx4j

I am trying to convert HTML to Docx using DOCX4J. We are using the following code. All of the conversion works except the table text is always Calibiri in Final Docx file. We try to handle this within the code, CSS and Docx4J without any success for last couple of days. It will be great if you can help.

```java
public String xhtmlToDocx(List<String> fileData, File destinationFile) {

    try {
        InputStream in;
        in = new FileInputStream(new File(TCellUtil.TCELL_DATA_LOG_FOLDER_PATH + File.separator + "Header_Temp.docx"));
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(in);
        System.out.println("before");
        for (String s : wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().fontsInUse())
            System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("aFTER ");
        VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);

        RFonts rfonts = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createRFonts();
        rfonts.setAscii("Times New Roman");
        rfonts.setHAnsi("Times New Roman");
        rfonts.setEastAsia("Times New Roman");
        XHTMLImporterImpl.addFontMapping("Times New Roman", rfonts);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getPropertyResolver().getDocumentDefaultRPr().setRFonts(rfonts);

        int c = 1;
        for (String xhtml : fileData) {
            String file_data = "<html>" + xhtml + "</html>";
            AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw" + c + ".html"));
            afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
            afiPart.setBinaryData(file_data.getBytes());

            Relationship altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(afiPart, AddPartBehaviour.REUSE_EXISTING);
            CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
            ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId());
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(createPageBreak());
            ((CTSettings) wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getDocumentSettingsPart().getJaxbElement()).setUpdateFields(new BooleanDefaultTrue());
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().convertAltChunks();

            for (String s : wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().fontsInUse())
                System.out.println(s);
            wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("docx", "text/html");
            c++;
        }
        XmlUtils.marshaltoString(wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true);
        wordMLPackage.save(destinationFile);
        this.dest_filePath = destinationFile.getAbsolutePath();

        return this.dest_filePath;
    } catch (Docx4JException var12) {
        var12.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception var13) {
        var13.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is whether docx4j is doing the conversion, or Word is doing it.

docx4j would be trying to do it if you specifically invoked docx4j-ImportXHTML, or if you used convertAltChunks().  Note that docx4j only converts an altChunk of type XHTML (ie not HTML).  So if it is an HTML altChunk, Word is doing the conversion.

In the code you posted:

```
           AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw"+c+".html"));

                   afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));

            afiPart.setBinaryData(file_data.getBytes());
```

So it is Word which is doing the conversion (and using Calibri in tables).

Also, be sure to check that your (X)HTML is well-formed XML.  If it isn't, you'll need to correct your input, either in the system which is emitting it, or by using some "tidy" code.

As a first step, make sure https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFile.java can process it.